# How to run registered exe in certain folder using Windows CLI (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, vagrant, command-line-interface

I have a vagrant installed and I want to create batch file which will run in from certain directory.
How can I do it?

Normally I do:

```
d:
cd vagrant
vagrant up
```

I would like to have something like:

```
d:\vagrant\vagrant up
```

But it does not work, as it says that name is not recognized

Comment: `start "vargant" /d "d:\vagrant\" /b /w "d:\vagrant\vagrant" up`  ?

Comment: Error: Windows cannot find file "d:\vagrant\vagrant"
As there is no "vagrant" file there, "vagrant" is added to PATH